# Rails Nested Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'd like the have the following routes:

```
sports/1
```

calls the `show` method for sport with id = 1.

```
sports/about/1
```

shows an "about" page for sport with id = 1.

Right now I have:

```
 resources :sports
```

in `routes.rb`.

If I try to go to

```
sports/about/1
```

I get an error because of course no sport has id = about.

Can I do something like this?

### Edit

To clarify, I just have an `about` action in my `sports_controller`.  Thanks for both methods though (controller and action)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do almost anything you want with rails routes.

EDIT: Now a more complete (and correct) solution:

First you declare a new REST action in the sports resource:

```
resources :sports do
  get 'about', :on => :member
end
```

Then, to change the normal URL behavior **url/sports/id/about** to **url/sports/about/id** you should use:

```
match 'sports/about/:id', :controller => 'sports', :action => 'about'}
```

Comment: What this does is call an "about" action inside the sports controller. Is that what you want or you actually have an abouts controller?

Comment: I just have an "about" action

Comment: I get a `undefined local variable or method `map' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007ffd33d54228>`.  Is this the 3.2.1 syntax?

Comment: Try using "match" instead of "map.connect"

Answer (score 1):

This should take care of your routes, but you really ought to [check out the RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) on the subject.

```
resources :sports do
  resources :about
end
```

This will give you routes like `sports/:sport_id/about/:id`. Of course you need to set the value of the sport in your `form_for(@sport, @about) do |f|` call or something like it.

Comment: the comment above makes a good point, I assumed presence of `AboutsController`.

Answer (score 0):

In the `routes.rb` write the following in the same order

```
match 'sports/about/:id' => 'sports#show', :as => :sport
resources :sports
```

To show a sport use `sport_path(@sport)`

Comment: Will this make both `sports/about/1` and `sports/1` go to the same action?

Comment: Yes, the url sports/1 will not match with the /sports/about/:id, but will match with the sports/1 which resources :sports generates. Both urls will call the show action in the sports controller

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the most straight forward way to do it:

```
resources :sports do
 collection do
resources 'about'
end
end
```

Or maybe:

```
namespace :sports do
 resources 'about'
end
```

Depending on whether you want a separate about controller or not.